# Objects and classes. How to print user input using a for loop?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

There are // that tell what i need help on. So I took user input and now I am trying to print the input using another method. The contents of my array wil have to be printed out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Running_Calcs {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int MAX_RUNNERS = 4;
    banner();
    Runner[] ar = new Runner[MAX_RUNNERS];
 // This is an array for user input. Getter and setter are already set for name,distance,time. 
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\nInformation for runner 1 / 3");
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = kbd.next();
        System.out.print("Miles: ");
        double distance = kbd.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Minutes: ");
        int time = kbd.nextInt();
    }

    kbd.close();
}

public static void printRunners(Runner[] ar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("First Print of runners");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println(ar[i]);
    }
    banner();

}
// I am trying to print the info from the array in this method. I don't know how. 
//Along with that , I am trying to print the pace and Temp which I already have in my other class. 
private static void banner() {
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Track runner info and pace\nGustavo Bruno");
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
}

}
```

Comment: If you have getters and setters, why don't you use them?

Comment: I have to call them in the PrintRunners method?

Comment: You have to instantiate a new runner in each iteration of the loop, set his attributes using those setter methods you have and store that instance in the array. In the printRunners method you have to call the corresponding getter methods for each runner.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to override the `ToString` method of the class Runner

and call it in the method `printRunners`

```
public static void printRunners(Runner[] ar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("First Print of runners");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println(ar[i].toString());   //here!!!
    }
    banner();

}
```

Comment: It stops printing info after my first for loop ends; before it gets to the printsRunners method.

Answer (score 0):

The main() method defines a variable named "ar" within the method.  This value will not be accessible outside of the method.  In order access it you need to declare it as a static variable of the class:

```
private static Runner[] ar;
```

When printing this out you need to loop over it:

```
for( Runner r : ar ){
    // somehow print out the Runner class (you haven't included this)
    System.out(r.getName() + "\t" + r.getDistance() + "\t" + r.getTime();
}
```

If your Runner

Now, the other problem you have is that nothing calls the printRunners() method.  I'm assuming that you want it to be called at the end of the main() method?